# URLConnection.setUseCaches(true) - when will cache expire?

Tags: android, caching, urlconnection, cache-expiration

I have a simple question: if I use URLConnection.setUseCaches(true) when loading something from web, when will those cached files expire? I'm developing for android, but it hardly makes any difference... So when will cache files be removed from SD card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837576/urlconnection-and-setusecachestrue) question's answer suggests that `URLConnection.setUseCaches(true)` has no effect.

What Neil then describes is how Android apps stored internally (phone memory) can also have cached content, held in /data/data/packagename/cache. To answer your original question but applied to this feature, the system is ultimately in control of these areas, although you are supposed to look after your own content, as described in the [API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).

Comment: If I save all files I need to getExternalCacheDir() and use URLConnection.setUseCaches(true), how can URLConnection know which file corresponds to which url? Or do I need to load those files manually (not through URLConnection)?

Comment: I think you'd need to do something about it manually - a quick idea might be to name the files using the hashCode() of the URL, and check if they exist first; if not, fall back to URLConnection.

Comment: The other thing to say is that if you're using a WebView, this has some built-in caching options - the cache ends up in the same place, but is managed for you to some extent - so you might find it easier to investigate that rather than reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 4):

If the UseCaches flag on a connection is **true, the connection is allowed to use whatever caches it can**. If **false, caches are to be ignored**. The default value comes from DefaultUseCaches, which defaults to true.**So,to use a cache you need to implement one on your own..Setting UseCaches flag to true jus lets you use the available cache.. but doesn't implement any cache on its own..